# Is there any performance difference between an NVMe SSD booted from BIOS and UEFI?

Tags: linux, boot, debian, ssd, bios

I bought an M.2 socket NVMe SSD and cloned my working debian installation to it (`sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/nvme0n1`). I noticed that the reading speed 1300MB/s (`sudo hdparm -tT /dev/nvme0n1`) on my Intel NUC6I5SYH is significantly lower than the rated speed 2300MB/s. So I was wondering if the initialisation of the SSD by the legacy BIOS booting process was the culprit.

I messed around for about 6 hours with all kinds of migration methods from BIOS to UEFI, e.g.,

`https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall`

`https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot`

I cannot get my drive bootable like the old BIOS one. In the end I was wondering if there is any performance difference between an SSD booted from BIOS and UEFI. If not, then the effort is simply not worth it, given that BIOS is still widely used.

So my first question is: can any one tell me if there is any actual performance difference between an SSD booted by the two different modes? I am not asking for the *booting* performance; I am asking about the performance once the computer has been booted, e.g., into desktop environment.

And the second question is: what is the correct way to migrate BIOS boot to UEFI with Debian (UEFI only, not CSM)? Is there a step-by-step guide on the web? Thanks.

Comment: M.2 SATA or PcI-e?

Comment: M.2 PCIe. SATA may not achieve 1300MB/s at the moment?

Comment: Your speed performance has nothing to do with legacy mode vs UEFI mode

Comment: What's the supported speed of your controller? After your system is up and running it depends on whatever you do whenever it would make a difference or not.

Comment: @Seth It's a plextor m8pe m.2 512GB. Its rating speed is 2500MB/s seq reading and 1400MB/s seq writing. But I only get 1000MB/s buffered disk reads using hdparm -tT /dev/nvme0n1. I have already switched from BIOS boot to UEFI boot. It was a long effort.

Comment: Yes but does the motherboard/CPU based controller actually support that speed?

Comment: @Seth I installed it on an Intel NUC6i5 with the latest bios. I'm quite sure nuc can use pcie 3.0 x4.

Comment: Do you use AHCI mode? Does the BIOS have a setting for the PCIe lanes that should be used? Did check the manual or did you not? From the technical specification 2.2.4.2: `Using PCIe x4 M.2 SSD maximum bandwidth is approximately 1600 MB/s`. Your initial question stated a reading speed of 1300 MB/s and now it's only 1000 MB/s so which is it?

Comment: @Seth I did use AHCI mode. The limitation of bandwidth was by the previous bios, see [link](http://nucblog.net/2016/05/skylake-nuc-bios-44-recovery-is-needed). Before I switched to UEFI (not fresh reinstall, I converted BIOS MBR to UEFI GPT), I got 1300MB/s from BIOS initialised M2 SSD but after the switch, I am getting 1000MB/s with UEFI booted SSD.

Comment: Not sure about the AHCI comment. SATA has AHCI or backward IDE mode. A PCI-e SSD has NVME.  (M.2 can be both SATA or PCI-e, but the OP stated that PCI-e was used).